Send file intent title
I'd like to send a file from my app to another app using an intent. My database stores metadata about the file and the file itself is uniquely identified by an UUID; the filename ends up being <uuid>.pdf. I would like to give people the ability to share the file, but when I now send the file, the <uuid>.pdf shows up as the title of the share sheet, instead of the name I provide and store in the database, how can I change this?
data class FileInfo(
    val id: UUID,
    var name: String,
    val uri: Uri
)

val fileInfo: FileInfo ...

val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileInfo.name)
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileInfo.uri)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    type = "application/pdf"
}

context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, fileInfo.name))


And EXTRA_TEXT?

Same result, as so for EXTRA_SUBJECT
